# Image not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I have done a webpage which has a moving image in the background.
 1. IE and Opera just shows the image **doesn't** move it. (The fonts **don't** work either)
 2. Chrome and Safari also **doesn't** move the image.(But fonts **are shown correctly**)
 3. Firefox **moves the image** as required.(But **fonts** are **not displayed**)

You can see the website here : http://ankitsuryawanshi.in/projects/404-html/

The (edited) CSS code is here :

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
@FONT-FACE
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive-Roman';
    src: url('../fonts/Chunkfive-roman-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Chunkfive-roman-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Chunkfive-roman-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/chunkfive-roman-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/chunkfive-roman-webfont.svg#ChunkFiveRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'BloklettersBalpen';
    src: url('../fonts/blokletters-balpen-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/blokletters-balpen-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/blokletters-balpen-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/blokletters-balpen-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/blokletters-balpen-webfont.svg#BloklettersBalpen') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
LETTERING SPECIFIC STYLES
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Logo H1 Text */
#logo .word1 {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

#logo .word1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    transition: width 0.2s;
}

#logo span:hover {
    top: 4px;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULTS
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    color: #000;
    background: #c1b69a url(../images/texture.jpg);
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive-Roman', sans-serif;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive-Roman', sans-serif;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    font-size: 114px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: #62b445 1px 1px 0, #62b445 2px 2px 0, #62b445 3px 3px 0, #45a5f6 4px 4px 0, #45a5f6 5px 5px 0, 5px 8px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}

h3 {
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #262626;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive-Roman', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #262626;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.written {
    font-family: 'BloklettersBalpen',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}

.written-small {
    font-family: 'BloklettersBalpen', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
}

/* About Page Definitions Area */
.col-def-plus p,.col-def-equals p {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.col-def p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

div.col-def p.word-break {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #000;
}

div.col-def p.word-def {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #333;
}

#shareTab {
    font-family: 'ChunkFive-Roman', sans-serif;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMON CLASSES
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.wrap {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fr {
    float: right;
}

.fl {
    float: left;
}

.ac {
    text-align: center;
}

.line-through {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
FLOATING BACKGROUND IMAGES
------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#clouds {
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(../images/clouds.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 736px;
    display: block;
}

@keyframes "float-clouds" {
 0% {
    background-position: 2400px 0;
 }
 100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes float-clouds {
 0% {
   background-position: 2400px 0;
 }
 100% {
   background-position: 0 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "float-clouds" {
 0% {
   background-position: 2400px 0;
 }
 100% {
   background-position: 0 0;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes "float-clouds" {
 0% {
   background-position: 2400px 0;
 }
 100% {
   background-position: 0 0;
 }

}

@-o-keyframes "float-clouds" {
 0% {
   background-position: 2400px 0;
 }
 100% {
   background-position: 0 0;
 }

}

#clouds {
    animation-name: float-clouds;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 95s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-duration: 95s;
    -o-animation-duration: 95s;
    -ms--animation-duration: 95s;
}
```

How do I correct everything here, so that it works correctly in all browsers.

Here is the JS code for the image movement :

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo h1, .nav-here-home, .nav-here-about, .home-page-tag h3, .about-page-tag h3, .written").lettering('words').children('span').lettering(); 
  $(".home-intro h2").fitText(.86); 
  $(".about-intro h2").fitText(.86);  

});        


// --------------------------------------------------- //
//             Background Image Floating               //
// --------------------------------------------------- //
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$.browser.webkit){
        var clouds = $('#clouds');
        var background = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            background -= 2;
            if (background == 1200) background = 0;
            clouds.css('background-position', background)
        }, 95)
    }
})
```

Where should I now edit it ?

Comment: Can you please trim the posted CSS to include only the relevant parts?

Comment: sure..just give me a min..

Comment: if you are using css `animation`, remember its one of the least supported features of css3 throughout.

Comment: razor : so what should I do now ?

Comment: @SanketBodhe You should use css animation and callback to Javascript for browsers not supporting it

Comment: check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787359/how-to-rotate-a-background-image-with-jquery). It might help.

Comment: but remember, the functionality you want to achieve may be compromised by this.

Comment: The same effect works here on IE and other browsers too...
http://www.pixelsincolors.com/demo/bara/bara/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a **[DEMO](http://output.jsbin.com/yaqofi)**.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Though you need to make few adjustments as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for the info..I will surely try it out.

Comment: But how do I add images here..
They haven't provided any option..!!

Comment: Well I edited the image url and it took it...But any specific code will help me move the image ?
You can see the site http://www.intellisult.com/ for refrence..!!

Comment: not egzactly but you can give that div blocks a background cloud image and adjust the positions on your screen. That is what this [site](http://intellisult.com) probably doing.

Comment: OK...and any guess why are fonts not diaplyed ?

Comment: Hello I hve added the Java script code to the question.Please tell me where should i correct it ?

Comment: have you try adding two additional scripts ? i.e. [Script1](http://jsbin.com/ekuguh/1/edit) and [Script2](http://jsbin.com/ekuguh/2/edit). As you may have notice during inspection.

Comment: Added them...still not working...Did you check the website http://intellisult.com/ ?

Comment: yes i did....they are using `animation` of css3 and plus a plugin.js file to float the images. Update your jquery version if it is outdated. update your website with latest code so others can see and comment. though i will see it tomorrow :|

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery .animate() - it does animation but using javascript instead of css3, css3's animate isn't fully supported as its still fairly new.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#clouds').animate({
          'background-position-x': '2400px',
          'background-position-y': '0'
      }, 95*1000, 'linear');
    });
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#clouds').animate({
        'background-position-x': '2400px',
        'background-position-y': '0'
      }, 95*1000, 'linear');
    }, 95*1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Just a small question..
Does this website use .animate feautre ?  
http://www.pixelsincolors.com/demo/bara/bara/

Comment: it is using the `animate()` feature of jquery api and it is a good approach too.

Comment: PLEASE HELP...WHERE DO I PUT THE CODE NOW ?

Comment: i am not sure about rotating the whole background, however we can switch them easily....i am trying a solution for it..will post it in few minutes.

Comment: You put the javascript code in a js file on the server as you would a css file, or embedded in the head of the document, have you worked out what the animate command needs to use to get the effect you want?

Comment: I have put the jquery files in the js folder of my website.
You can see them using chrome...
If you feel I should paste some file there please do help me.
And what about the fonts..which are not displayed in IE,Opera and Firefox.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code to replicate what your css3 animation was doing, put this in the <head> of your page, hope this helps

Comment: Nope..Not working.Shall I give you the whole folder so you can figure it out ?

Comment: you need to make sure the page is loading jquery, make sure the first script tags src points to your jquery file or change the whole line to <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Hey they are now moving...but it takes approximately 2-3 min to load...Can something make it faster ?

Comment: Nope still not working..it is still taking..time...!!
I dont understand why is it taking so much time ?

Comment: there was a small typo in the last update, really sorry try the code now

Comment: No....Still not working as said...Just check this site :
http://intellisult.com/
It works on this site..

Comment: Hello I hve added the Java script code to the question.Please tell me where should i correct it ?

Comment: I have changed my answer again, the reason the movement doesn't start automatically is because the loop to make it animate over and over doesn't start until after the looping amount of time, I have added the animate function to start as soon as the page loads now too