# change background image in loop

Tags: jquery

i want to change background image of page using `jQuery` onclick would look like this:

```
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'];
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', colors[1]);
})
```

but i want to change it automatically using some short of 'jQuery` function, my try so far is this :

```
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'];

$.each(colors, function(color){
    setTimeout(function(){$('body').css('background', color)}, 1000);
});
```

but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787359/how-to-rotate-a-background-image-with-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787359/how-to-rotate-a-background-image-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'];

$.each(colors, function(i, color){
    setTimeout(function(){$('body').css('background', color)}, (i+1)*1000);
});
```

I made two changes :

- the first argument given to the callback is the index, not the element of the array
- I give different delays using the index to compute the delay

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'],
    colorIndex = 0,
    $body = $('body');

setInterval(function(){ $body.css('background', colors[colorIndex++ % colors.length])}, 1000);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8uZga/